# H(z) out of plot zero diagram

Tags: matlab, filter, plot

Hello I wonder If anyone can help me with getting the H(z) out of this image.
[image]

I have managed to solve this next one, but the poles are different this time and I do not know how to deal with this problem. Can anybody help me?
[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about it lacks a basic understanding of the problem and is not related to programming

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math, and should go to the math.SE site instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this isn't really related to MATLAB, but you have 3 poles (x) and 3 zeros (o). Write their values down and then you pretty much have your transfer function `H(z)`, as in your second example. I could do it for you, but then you wouldn't learn anything... It doesn't get much simpler than this...

Comment: I need to find the H(z) to transform it into a x(t) which I will input in MATLAB. Sorry If this is a bad question.
Can you help me out with it? I actually need it for my finals and I am stuck with this bit. I do not know how to put the zero in the center and the poles outside the circle into the equation.
I guess the zeros will be:
z-(0,5+0,5i)
z-(0,5-0,5i)
z-(0-0i)
and the poles:
z-(1)
z-(-1-i)
z-(-1+i)
Zeroes will be in the numarator and poles will be in the denominator. But how exactly will it look like? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Like I said, write down the values of the poles and the zeros. The denominator is the product of `(z-p_i)` where `p_i` are your poles, and the numerator is the product of `(z-z_i)` where `z_i` are your zeroes. This is really basic stuff, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole%E2%80%93zero_plot.

Comment: I guess the zeros will be: z-(0,5+0,5i); z-(0,5-0,5i); z-(0-0i) and the poles: z-(1); z-(-1-i); z-(-1+i) Zeroes will be in the numarator and poles will be in the denominator. But how exactly will it look like?

Comment: You're right, I edited my comment. Just multiple them together and you have your numerator and denominator. Suggestion `z-(0-0i)` is simply `z` as `0+/-0i = 0`...